# Failed to render the images from Flicker

Tags: html, css

Trying out the image blog application to understand `float`prpertiy of CSS. As the link is accurate from Flickr Photo Website, the webpage is unable to render the images.

Tried to look up w3schools for syntax of img tag of HTML.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photos.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>

    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/qh8u7t">
    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/nZybCW">
    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/odUZLT">

    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/pnzXJv">
    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/qyz47B">
    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/q2PmdR">

    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/nM4vbe">
    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/fvVSdn">
    <img src="https://flic.kr/p/drtH69">

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your urls are pointing at the flickr _page_ for the image, not the image itself. You can't use a page as an image src. And I don't know what flickr's hot-linking policy is.

Comment: @rayhatfield thanks for the help. Bit confused to make image Grid. Is there any other solution to render the images from internet in this project?

Comment: `<img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7486/15935086719_2f74565730_o.jpg>``
did not work as well !

Comment: You shouldn’t use Flickr as image hosting, you can google another service, there is a lot

Comment: You need to add https:    ‘https:// live.staticflickr.com/7486/15935086719_2f74565730_o.jpg’ Don’t forget to delete space before _live_

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You can include images from other sites (if they allow it) but you have to point the src at the image (the jpg, png, gif, etc.), not the page. so `<img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3711/14293417933_c5d8fb7666_k.jpg"/>` works, but `<img src="https://flic.kr/p/qh8u7t">` doesn't.

Comment: Thank  your for your response. It worked with Image Link. Flicker has new guideline to embed the Common Creative Licence based images to put into third party projects. !